# Compare typescript objects and add diff to new object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Within my Angular application, I need to compare two typescript objects and create a new object that consists of key/value pairs where the value of the key is different in the second object.

Here is my code:

```
const objBefore = {id: 100088, firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Smith", notes: null};
const objAfter = {id: 100088, firstName: "John", lastName: "Johnson", notes: null};

let newObj = {};

for(let key in objBefore) {
    if (objBefore[key] !== objAfter[key]) {

        let newEntry = { key:  objAfter[key]}
        Object.assign(newObj, newEntry)
    }
}

console.log(newObj)
```

The output is:

```
{ key: 'Johnson' }
```

I need the output to be:

```
{ firstName: "John", lastName: "Johnson" }
```

How do I assign the value of the key (e.g., firstName) instead of the variable (key)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use square brackets on [key]

```
const objBefore = {id: 100088, firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Smith", notes: null};
const objAfter = {id: 100088, firstName: "John", lastName: "Johnson", notes: null};

let newObj = {};

for(let key in objBefore) {
    if (objBefore[key] !== objAfter[key]) {

        let newEntry = { [key]:  objAfter[key]}
        Object.assign(newObj, newEntry)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I've been trying to figure this out for hours! Thank you for the quick response!